# redirect after Blazor Webassembly authentication

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

I just started to work on Blazor recently. I am trying to add authentication process to my Blazor app. The oidc authentication is added in program.cs as:

```
builder.services.addOidcAuthentication(
        options =>{
          builder.Configuration.Bind("oidc", options.ProviderOptions);
    }
  );
```

passed my params in the appsettings:

```
{
    "oidc" : {
          
        ...
        RediectUri :"https://mysite/project"

}
```

where "https://mysite/project" would be the index page of my app. I am able to connect to the server and authenticated with my login. However, it could only be redirect to the index page. I do have other pages under Pages but always got a 404 if i tried to redirect it to "https://mysite/project/pagename".

Answer (score 0):

On **.NET 7 Blazor WASM app** you can return to the referred page using:

RedirectToLogin.razor

```
@inject NavigationManager Navigation
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Options

@inject IOptionsSnapshot<RemoteAuthenticationOptions<ApiAuthorizationProviderOptions>> Options
@code {

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Navigation.NavigateToLogin(Options.Get(Microsoft.Extensions.Options.Options.DefaultName).AuthenticationPaths.LogInPath);
    }
}
```

See original post: https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/497#issue-1414759756